# Xcode Swift Table View: Use of Slider and SegmentedControl as custom cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am currently using numerous custom cells in a tableview, of which consist of sliders and segmented controls. My issue is that in the simulator, when these rows are selected, the values of the sliders and pickers are reset to default. So for example, if I changed the value of the slider to 10, and then selected the row of the slider, the slider's value would reset to 0. I am trying to diagnose this issue so when the row is selected, the value remains the same; however, I am not sure where this problem arises. I have a hunch that it has something to do with .dequeueReusableCell or .reloadData, but I do not have a great grasp of what they do to start debugging.

Below is my code for cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    // I am using identifiers to set Titles within the TableView
    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellNormal" {
        if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = primaryTitle as? String
        }

        eventType = ((cellDescriptors[0] as! NSMutableArray)[0] as! NSDictionary)["primaryTitle"]! as! String
        if let secondaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = secondaryTitle as? String
        }
    }
    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
        cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }


    else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellValuePicker" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
    }


    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Code from CustomCell, my class for all my cells

```
//outlet properties
@IBOutlet weak var moneyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var moneySlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var privacy: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    moneyValue = Int(sender.value)
    moneyLabel.text = String(moneyValue)
    moneyAmount = moneyLabel.text!

}

@IBAction func privacyChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    switch privacy.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        print("public")
        privacyDescription = "public"
    case 1:
        print("private")
        privacyDescription = "private"
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you upload some of your code? I think it has something to do with how you implemented `cellForRowAtindexPath`.

Comment: @JustinRose I currently don't have any code related to my sliders or pickers in my cellForRowAtindexPath function, but I was toying around with it earlier. Could this be the issue? I thought cellForRowAtindexPath is used for initializing the table at each rows? Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: It looks as you only have one custom cell. Are you manipulating the sliders in any way in `CustomCell`?

Comment: The only thing I am manipulating in CustomCell are for when the slider value is changed. Also I meant to say that I am using segmented controls and not pickers - sorry for any confusion!